# Reverse for 'add_items' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_items\\/(?P<pizza_name>[^/]+)\\/$']

Tags: python, django

how to resolve this error and I also want to send multilple variables with this url

```
Reverse for 'add_items' with arguments '('1 Topping',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_items\\/(?P<pizza_name>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

**index.html**

```html
<table>
        {% for pizza in r_pizzas %}

        <tr><a href="{% url 'add_items' pizza.pizza_type %}">{{pizza.pizza_type}}  , {{pizza.small}}   , {{pizza.large}}</a> </tr><br><hr>

        {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("login" , views.login_view , name="login"),
path("logout" , views.logout_view , name="logout"),
path("register" , views.register , name="register"),
path("registration_successful" , views.registered , name="registered"),
path("add_items/<pizza_name>/" , views.add_items , name="add_items")


]
```

**views.py**

```
def add_items(request , pizza_name ):
item = pizza_name
```

**related model**

```
class Sicilian_Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza_type = models.CharField(max_length=64 ,  default=None)
    small = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2 , default=None)
    large = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2 , default=None)
```

Comment: Well this is definitely *not* a slug, it is the `str(..)` of the `pizza_type`. Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem post edited with related model

Comment: Well as said before the `pizza_type` is *not* a slug, so I would advice to make a slug field. It might even be better to make a `PizzaType` model, and thus use a `ForeignKey` to that model.

Comment: If there is not an option to make a slug field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern says you're passing a slug:

```
path("add_items/<slug:pizza_name>/" , views.add_items , name="add_items")
```

But you're passing in a string. If you don't have an option to make a slug field, change the URL conf. Off-hand, I think this would work:

```
path("add_items/<pizza_name>/", views.add_items, name="add_items")
```

Comment: If I do so as `path("add_items/<pizza_name>/", views.add_items, name="add_items")` then I am getting error like that
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add_items' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_items\\/(?P<pizza_name>[^/]+)\\/$']`